# How do you configure a binary environment variable with Symfony YAML configuration?

Tags: symfony, yaml

Suppose I have `FOO=dGVzdA==` in my `.env` file and then I try to load this binary environment variable in my YAML configuration.

```yaml
foo: !!binary '%env(FOO)%'
```

This errors out because it tries to decode `%env(FOO)%` verbatim as if it were base64-encoded. That is, it does not substitute the environment variable when prefixed with `!!binary`. So then, how does one actually use a binary environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the correct way to express this is:

```yaml
foo: '%env(base64:FOO)%'
```